# Filtering list of files to those recently edited

Tags: files, time-date

Suppose I have a list of files:

```el
(setq files '("/path/to/file1" ...))
```

Is there a way to reduce this list to only those files which were edited within the past, say, 10 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to reduce this list to only those files which were edited within the past, say, 10 days?

Something like this?  It assumes Emacs 26+, but to support earlier versions you can easily replace `(file-attribute-modification-time ...)` with `(nth 5 ...)`, `seq-filter` with other ways of filtering lists, the `nil` argument to `time-subtract` with `(current-time)`, etc.

```el
(autoload 'seq-filter "seq")

(defun my-files-since (files days)
  "Return subset of FILES modified within the last DAYS."
  (let ((since (time-subtract nil (days-to-time days))))
    (seq-filter (lambda (file)
                  (let* ((attrs (file-attributes file))
                         (mtime (file-attribute-modification-time attrs)))
                    (time-less-p since mtime)))
                files)))

(my-files-since '("/path/to/foo" "bar" ...) 10)
```

References:

- [`(info "(elisp) File Attributes")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Attributes.html)
- [`(info "(elisp) Time Calculations")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Calculations.html)
- [`(info "(elisp) Sequence Functions")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html)